# How do I get an animating function with multiple cases that are controlling the CSS value in Javascript to render?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up my Java script so that I can animate an object from the top to the bottom of the screen over and over again calling different items to fall randomly. Right now I can't figure out to get one of the objects to fall.

I've tried adding the css via my CSS through java script but I'm not sure that is the best option.

```js
function myMove() {

  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("boxcontainer");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 725);

  function frame() {
    if (pos == 725) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + "25px";
    }
  }
}

elem.addEventListener("mousedown", function turnTetrisleft() {
  switch (keycode) {
    case Key.LEFT:
      elem.style.transform.rotateX() += 90 + "deg";
      break;
    case Key.RIGHT:
      elem.style.transform.rotateX() -= 90 + "deg";
      break;
    default:
      elem.style.transform.rotateX() += "";
  }
});
```

```css
.boxcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 750px;
  top: 25px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tetris-display">

  <div class="tetris-item">
    <div class="boxcontainer">
      <div class="block">
        <div class="innerblock block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block">
        <div class="innerblock block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block box">
        <div class="innerblock block"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="block box">
        <div class="innerblock block"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I can't see anything happening. I've had several errors about the brackets but I can't see any errors currently

Comment: `elem` is an array of elements, not a unique element

Comment: isn't it a variable? @OmriAttiya

Comment: its a variable but its an array.

Comment: @OmriAttiya so what would you do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `turnTetrisleft` function you're referencing all of the elements, not the currently clicked element.

Something like this may work:

```
elem.addEventListener("mousedown", function turnTetrisleft(event) {
  switch (keycode) {
    case Key.LEFT:
      event.target.style.transform.rotateX() += 90 + "deg";
      break;
    case Key.RIGHT:
      event.target.style.transform.rotateX() -= 90 + "deg";
      break;
    default:
      event.target.style.transform.rotateX() += "";
  }
});
```

Note the `event` and the `event.target`

Comment: What key statement? I copied your code and replaced "elem" inside the function with "event.target".

Answer (score 0):

You're having a couple of problems here.

1. `elem` is not an element, it's an array.
2. `elem` is defined only inside the function `myMove` but your try to use it outside the function where it's undefined.
3. In the event listener - `keycode` is not defined. `Key` is not defined. That is not the way to use rotate (read [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_transform.asp)).
4. I'm suggesting for you to try and read about [css animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp). You will achieve better results with less effort.

It looks messy and I think you need to rethink about what you are doing there because there are too many things to fix.

I hope you will learn from this and improve and finally achieve your results!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
elem.style.transform.rotateX() += 90 + "deg";
```

looks incorrect. `elem.style.transform` is a string that has no method `rotateX()`

You should have it written as

```
var angle = ...;
angle += 90;
elem.style.transform = angle.toString() + "deg";
```

Comment: interesting I might try this but I don't think this changes the issue